# Does OpenAI ChatGPT has any "dialogue state tracking" besides max tokens to include previous conversation history?

Tags: chatgpt, memory

When I chat with chatGPT earlier, chatGPT itself mentioned "dialogue state tracking" technique that is utilized in addition to chat completion with previous conversation history(up to max allowed tokens).

Is this just a specific technique or this is just some general term. As a specific technique, can we outline how it is done?

The background this question is that it seems chatGPT can take a very long initial "instruction", e.g. like [a tutor prompt with detailed behavior protocol](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevGuyRash/rashino-prompts/condensed-prompt/prompts/ai_tutor_v2.md).

And even after a few rounds questions, it still behave as instructed pretty completely and not wondering off back to its normal style.

Really want to know how it can achieve this and is the open ai API side of chatCompletion
can do the same or not.

Comment: ChatGPT probably doesn't know how ChatGPT works, and it's known to hallucinate.